# Updating the Comparator in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a select form with multiple options for sorting.

I'm listening for change on this form, and want to update my comparator with the input value and sort my collection from there.

My thought was to try to set the property directly:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortBy').change(function()
      {
        collection.set({ 'comparator': $('#sortBy').val() })
        alert("This worked");
      });
});
```

But I'm not having any luck.

How can you update the comparator without doing so in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

setting the comparator directly on the collection will not work. you can call

```
collection.sortBy(comparator);
```

or

```
collection.sort(comparator);
```

sortBy is the underscore sortBy method: see here for docs http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy
sort is (I believe) javascript sort: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Where in my backbone code would I call this? Calling it after defining everything has firebug saying that collection is undefined.. (same with using this.collection)

Comment: In the view try events: { 'click #sortBy': 'myListener' }, then,   myListener: function(e) { this.collection.sortBy(e.currentTarget.value) } // untested but I think you get the idea :)

Comment: Btw, you can get rid of the document.ready wrapper. You don't need it in backbone if you use the events hash on the view since backbone will delegate everything to this.$el for you